# Sending Image from Android with Retrofit and Getting the Image with Python Flask

Tags: python, android, flask, retrofit2

I am trying to send an image to flask endpoint from android application using retrofit 2 but I seem to fail every time. Flask endpoint is working with both html and postman posts so the problem is on the retrofit part.

Here is the Flask endpoint:

```
@app.route("/uploadfile", methods=["POST"])
def uploadsingle():
    file = request.files['file']
    file.save(os.path.join("/home/moralalp/mysite/", file.filename))
    return "Success"
```

Below is the interface for retrofit:

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploadfile")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(@Part("description") RequestBody description, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And finally, the uploadFile method:

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {

    final EditText name = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    RequestBody descriptionPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, name.getText().toString());

    File originalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));

    RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), originalFile);

    MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", originalFile.getName(), filePart);

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://mysite.pythonanywhere.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = client.uploadPhoto(descriptionPart, file);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YEAH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

I keep getting "NOOO" Toast message so I can not even get a response, what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

As for this error please use the next line to figure out what is the problem and please edit your question to contain it

```
@Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error_TAG", "onFailure: Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
```

After that Please Filter your log cat to the `Error_TAG` and Add the Error in the Question

Good Luck

Comment: I added the solution to my problem but can I use it in the production?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so adding the following in the AndroidManifest.xml file solved my problem:

```
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```